# How to django-auth-ldap achieve authentication with cn (common name) in AD?

Tags: python, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I'm using Active directory with windows server 2008 R2. I have an application running with Django and python 2.7. Now I need to use active directory authentication to access into my application.

To do that, i'm using this packages:

```
sudo apt-get-update
sudo apt-get install python-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libssl-dev
sudo pip install django-auth-ldap 
sudo pip install python-ldap
```

I used the full name to have a successful bind.

```
import ldap
from django.conf import settings

username='my full name in AD'
password= 'my password'

l = ldap.initialize(settings.AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI)
l.simple_bind_s(username,password)
```

[image]

My problem is when i'm trying to use my cn attribute for bind, i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 207, in     
simple_bind_s
return self.result(msgid,all=1,timeout=self.timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 422, in 
result res_type,res_data,res_msgid = self.result2(msgid,all,timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 426, in  
result2 res_type, res_data, res_msgid, srv_ctrls =       
self.result3(msgid,all,timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 432, in 
result3 ldap_result = self._ldap_call(self._l.result3,msgid,all,timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 96, in   
_ldap_call result = func(*args,**kwargs)
INVALID_CREDENTIALS: {'info': '80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment:   
AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1', 'desc': 'Invalid 
credentials'}
```

[image]

Can I use my cn (common name)attribute for authentication to my Active directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the cn value in your simple_bind().  Use the alternate user principal name `sAMAccountName@FQDN` instead, or one of the other [supported bind names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223499.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

@marabu, thanks for the reply. You're right, ican't use any editor attribute (like cn, ....) in the simple bind.
we have an access  to this attribute only by search method after having a successfull bind.
In my case i have two choices:

1) simple_bind_s(full_name, password)

2) simple_bind_s(sAMAccountName@FQDN, password) if we are using email address to our session authenticate

like this:

[image]